Prove that: $a\cdot IA^2+b\cdot IB^2+c\cdot IC^2=abc$.
Given triangle $ABC$ with $BC=a, CA=b, AB=c$,
let $I$ be the center of the circle inscribed in the triangle.
Prove that: $a\cdot IA^2+b\cdot IB^2+c\cdot IC^2=abc$.

Did you copy and paste here? Did you try to read what you posted?

Welcome to MSE! I recommend to type your question in Latex, otherwise it is quite hard to understand.

Here is a way of brute force to solve this.
Let $P,Q,R$ be the intersection point of the inscribed circle with $BC,CA,AB$ respectively. Denote:
$$ \begin{cases} x:=AQ=AR\\
y:=BP=BR\\
z:=CP=CQ \end{cases} $$
Then:
$$ \begin{cases}
x+y=c\\
y+z=a\\
z+x=b
\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}
x=\frac{b+c-a}{2}\\
y=\frac{c+a-b}{2}\\
z=\frac{a+b-c}{2}
\end{cases}$$
Now it suffices to show
$$ \begin{aligned}
&a\cdot IA^2+b\cdot IB^2+c\cdot IC^2-abc=0\\
\iff & a(r^2+x^2)+b(y^2+r^2)+c(z^2+r^2)-abc=0\\
\end{aligned}$$
Substituting $x,y,z$ to see it is reduced to (after a tedious verification)
$$ p\cdot r^2=(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)$$
where $p:=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ is the semi circumstance of the triangle. This equation is indeed true, since by Heron's formula:
$$ r^2=\frac{S^2}{p^2}=\frac{(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}{p}$$

Please refrain from answering poor quality questions, e.g., problem statement + demanding an answer.

thank you so much you are so pro
